# How to send notification to other Twilio Chat member if the one member left the chat?

Tags: java, twilio-programmable-chat

In my project, i have implemented Twilio for one to one chat, user can initiate chat from mobile app and operator will respond from web application.

So if chat is going on between user and operator and suddenly user close the chat then how operator will come to know that user has left the chat and vise-versa?

Comment: +2 is quite unusual for a brief question of this kind. If people you know are upvoting your content, please ask them to desist - voting rings are usually met with suspension here.

Comment: Check the "Handle Member Events" in docs. https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/channels?code-sample=code-get-a-channel-from-a-channel-descriptor&code-language=Android%20-%20Java&code-sdk-version=default#delete-a-channel

Comment: @halfer i will make sure from next that will not add that kind of phrases in the question.